# .htaccess to set root of domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a domain pointing to the IP of external hosting via the DNS 'A Type'.  The hosting has many sites held their, eg:

- www.[myhostdomain].com/site1/ = www.[site1].com
- www.[myhostdomain].com/site2/ = www.[site2].com
- www.[myhostdomain].com/site3/ = www.[site3].com

I need to set the root of my domain so that for all intents and purposes it just shows the domain, not the hosting address.  eg www.[site3].com or www.[site3].com/about-us etc...

I understand this can be done with rewrite code within .htaccess?  Support or guidance with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule in the `/site1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?site1\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.site1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

You will need similar rules in all the sites like site2, site3 etc.